# Не могу установить модуль pycrypto

Tags: python, pip

```
pip3 install pycrypto
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: нужен перевод фразы `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required`?

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ )

Comment: Я это видел ,не работает

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что библиотека устаревшая, нужно ставить:

`pip install pycryptodome`

Либо:

`pip install pycryptodomex`

С ними уже проблем быть не должно, у самого такая проблема была.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй Downgrade`нуть версию питона. У меня было такое же, и даунгрейд помог

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]